# Deploying Angular app in Azure and configuring CI/CD using VSTS

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-deployment

I'm learning to deploy an Angular app in Azure and configuring CI/CD using VSTS.

So, I created AngularHeroes app based on [this](https://angular.io/tutorial) tutorial.

Created a new resource (Web App service) in Azure.

In VSTS, created a new project, added a VSTS repository and cloned it to local to push the angular app code. For setting up CI/CD I followed [this msdn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wael-kdouh/2017/09/11/deploying-your-angular-application-to-azure-using-visual-studio-team-services-vsts/) article. And queued the build definition but it got failed with the following error, "npm failed with return code 4294963238".
So, I checked [this git](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/6657) article.

Also, I configured azure app's Deployment Options with this VSTS project.
And pushed the code from local to VSTS repo and try to run the build again but got the same error.

So, I'm stuck and figuring out the missing pieces. Please let me know what's wrong here...

I have also attached screenshots for configuring [image: Publish artifacts], [image: Build definiton] and [image: Release definition], for more understanding about configuration.

Answer (score 1):

1) Create account on VSTS and create project

[image]

2) If you have code on VSTS then add code

[image]

3)  Go to build tab and click build

4) Now create pipeline

4.1) click on build and create build pipline

[image]

4.2) Add bitbucket or any other version control from list for code source

[image]

4.3 ) select npm and add following commands

[image]

4.4) Select another npm and add following command

[image]

4.5) Now select command line and add following command

[image]

4.6) Create another npm and following commands

[image]

4.7)  one more npm and add following commands
[image]

4.8 ) Select Azure App Service Deploy and add following commands

[image]

4.9) Final steps

[image]

5 ) clicked save and queue and will show you result , you can configure email notification also

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, seems it's related to the caches. This thread for your reference : https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1205

So, just try to **enable the Clean source directory** in the first **Get sources** step, then try it again.

Alternatively you can try to create a new definition, then try it again.

[image]

Comment: @GauravKrishn Have you resolved the issue? any update?